# Orderby a string column in linq causes an error

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query like this :

```
 List<PresentClass.userpresentation> q =
     (dbconnect.tblUsers.Where(
       i => i.permission == permission)
       .Select(arg => new PresentClass.userpresentation { 
       email = arg.email, pass = arg.password, 
       name = arg.name+" "+arg.family })).ToList();
```

After adding an **orderby** :

```
 List<PresentClass.userpresentation> q =
     (dbconnect.tblUsers.Where(
     i => i.permission == permission)
     .Select(arg => new PresentClass.userpresentation { 
     email = arg.email, pass = arg.password, 
     name = arg.name+" "+arg.family })).OrderBy(i=>i.family).ToList();
```

I got this error :

> The member
>   'Novitiate.AdminPortal.PresentationClass.PresentClass+userpresentation.family'
>   has no supported translation to SQL.

My class:

```
 public class userpresentation
 {
    public string username { set; get; }
    public string email { set; get; }
    public string family { set; get; }
    public string name { set; get; }
    public  string pass{ set; get; }
 }
```

Why?

Comment: because there is no `family` property on `userpresentation`

Comment: there is a family property in my class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's trying to translate the OrderBy() into a SQL statement on your projection.

Try adding the OrderBy() before Select() if you want the database to do the ordering, or after the ToList() if you want to do the ordering once the collection has been loaded.

```
var q = (dbconnect.tblUsers.Where(i => i.permission == permission)
                           .OrderBy(i=>i.family)
                           .Select(arg => new PresentClass.userpresentation { 
                               email = arg.email, 
                               pass = arg.password, 
                               name = arg.name+" "+arg.family 
                            })).ToList();
```